# How to make H264 (.mp4) streaming module to work with lighttpd 1.5

Tags: lighttpd, streaming

H264 is not working with lighttpd 1.5, but it's ok with 1.4
Any suggestions?

Comment: I have only be able to get mod_h264_streaming to work with lighttpd 1.4.18, myself.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions? Here is a fully explain documents and working server: http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Lighttpd-Version2#DownloadLighttpd1.5.0

Comment: Still not working? Give us more details about OS, your configuration etc.